# "TypeError - Property not Function" - Firebreath plugin on Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome-extension, osx-lion, firebreath

This is the JavaScript code in the Chrome background.html.

```
var plugin = document.getElementById("reverbPlugin");
if (!plugin.startBackgroundThread()) {
        console.log("Failed to start background thread: " + plugin.getErrorMessage());
        return;
}
```

Here is the HTML part of it.

```
<embed type="application/x-reverbbrowserplugin" id="reverbPlugin"></embed>
```

The exception I'm getting on the JavaScript code is, `TypeError - property_not_function`.

My library (the `BrowserPlugin.plugin` file created after compiling the Firebreath project) is a non-fat binary for x86_64 arch on Mac OS X Lion.

Any ideas on why the function is not found by JavaScript? Am I missing something obvious?
(Let me know any more information is needed).

Thanks!

PS. I had a [similar problem for Firefox plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442509/couldnt-find-function-symbol-in-library-js-ctypes) using JS-Ctypes, but was solved. I tried the similar approach on this one and tried different function names. Didn't work.

Comment: It may be that "startBackgroundThread" is **void**. In your link to "similar problem for Firefox plugin" it is **void** not a function. So "**if (!**plugin.startBackgroundThread()..." is wrong.

Comment: startBackgroundThread is a function returning an integer.

Comment: return true or false or a number ?

Comment: Sorry. Its a boolean. Returns true/false.

Comment: you have it changed quickly. 7 hours before it was void in your library. My C + + library **function** is RFD_startBackgroundThread int (). But that is not right. You can see this in the mangled name. **__Z25RFD_startBackgroundThreadv** The last letter is a " v " stands for **void**. Regardless, what do you think that it is and what it really is.

Comment: Well, I'm getting a return value from the function, meaning that it is not void, as the declaration of the function says. I'm just wondering if it is a similar problem with Chrome - mangled function name. Apparently not. I tried the mangled name, the error is the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13807/discussion-between-rahul-jiresal-and-moskito-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that you need to call registerMethod for that method name in your JSAPI object. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this has changed recently, Chrome does not support 64 bit plugins.  Try building it i386

Next, I recommend using an object tag instead of an embed tag.

If it still says no such method, you may have forgotten to call registerMethod in the constructor of your JSAPI object.

(updated to include items from the comments below)

Comment: Changed the file to a [fat binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary) containing both i386 and x86_64. The same problem persists. `Object #<HTMLEmbedElement> has no method 'startBackgroundThread'`!

Comment: Don't use an embed use an object tag

Comment: Now the error says `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'startBackgroundThread' of object <JSAPI-Auto Javascript Object> is not a function`. I also printed out the object `plugin` to see if I'm getting the object, it now says `<JSAPI-Auto Javascript Object>`. Earlier it was `[object HTMLEmbedElement]`.

Comment: @RahulJiresal. That's what i sayed . IT IS NOT A FUNCTION . Have you tried to call it with "plugin.startBackgroundThread();" **without if** ?

Comment: if you're getting "<JSAPI-Auto Javascript Object>" then it definitely is loading the plugin. as @moskito-x suggests you may not have correctly exposed your function. What happens when you call it natively? Did you call registerMethod for that method name in your JSAPI object?

Comment: @taxilian. +1 You can explain it better. Because my english is not so good. It may also the just compiled and the dll in the plugin folder are not the same.

Comment: @taxilian. I made a stupid mistake. I did not call registerMethod in the JSAPI object. Sigh. :-/